# Why this code shows wrong message (ignore the first XML element using python)

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to ignore the first XML element using python and found one resolve here but this doesn't work for me.

please look at this follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Story>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">some link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link i want to find</a></li>
       </ul>
    </Story>
</Root>
```

I want to ignore only the first li element and print all.

So i found this code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("C:\\ignore_first.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

ignore_first = root.findall('.//li[position()>1]')

print(ignore_first)
```

Where is wrong? this code shows SyntaxError: unsupported function.
I don't think li[position()>1] is accepted in python.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and copy/paste the _actual_, _complete_ error message (format as code).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python documentation for XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax), only a small subset of XPath syntax is supported.

You can use `[n]` to select a particular item by position, but the more general `position()` function is not supported.

> `[position]`  Selects all elements that are located at the given position. The *position* can be either an integer (1 is the first position), the expression `last()` (for the last position), or a position relative to the last position (e.g. `last()-1`).

If you want to ignore the first element you will have to iterate over the collection yourself.